# getPageInfo method of FB doesn't work with https

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

FB Javascript SDK getPageInfo doesn't call the callback function inside it when https is turned on facebook

```
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(
  function(pageinfo) {
    scrollBarPosition = pageinfo.scrollTop;
    console.log("scrollbarposition"+scrollBarPosition);
  });`
```

console.log is not printed in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you have encountered a regression in the API: [Link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/342009985869471/&ei=5lB7UOi3EKeY0QGUh4DIAw&usg=AFQjCNEg1wjsf5xUWFA6C1C1qk3LR7xHNg&sig2=MBVeP5o6k1OgbSX3jAE4ug)

I would file a bug if I were you.

Comment: Tried to create a bug and it is taking for ever  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Comment: Nevermind could file a bug this timehttps://developers.facebook.com/bugs/124862424330123

Comment: It does fire a console statements if i turn off secure browsing setting